# How to maintain Singleton class for Web Socket Connection in Android Hilt-dagger?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I am new to Android Dagger-Hilt and I found it useful for my project. However, recently I want to use this concept to get my `ServerConnection` class to become Singleton across different view (fragment and activity). How can I achieve that?

I had tried to approach below but I can't get it Singleton as it will create 2 `ServerConnection` instance in my fragment/activity view. Where had I do wrong?

Current approach

AppModule.kt

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideSocketConnection(tokenDao: TokenDao) : ServerConnection{
    val token = runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) { tokenDao.find() }
    val tok = token!!.token
    val refreshToken = token.refresh_token
    return ServerConnection(URL)
}
```

ServerConnection.kt

```
class ServerConnection(url: String) {
    enum class ConnectionStatus {
        DISCONNECTED, CONNECTED
    }

    interface ServerListener {
        fun onNewMessage(message: String?)
        fun onStatusChange(status: ConnectionStatus?)
    }
    

    private var mWebSocket: WebSocket? = null
    private val mClient: OkHttpClient
    private val mServerUrl: String
    private var mMessageHandler: Handler? = null
    private var mStatusHandler: Handler? = null
    private var mListener: ServerListener? = null

    init {
        mClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .build()
        mServerUrl = url
    }

    private inner class SocketListener : WebSocketListener() {
        override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
            val m = mStatusHandler!!.obtainMessage(0, ConnectionStatus.CONNECTED)
            mStatusHandler!!.sendMessage(m)
        }

        override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
            val m = mMessageHandler!!.obtainMessage(0, text)
            mMessageHandler!!.sendMessage(m)
        }

        override fun onClosed(
            webSocket: WebSocket,
            code: Int,
            reason: String
        ) {
            val m =
                mStatusHandler!!.obtainMessage(0, ConnectionStatus.DISCONNECTED)
            mStatusHandler!!.sendMessage(m)
        }

        override fun onFailure(
            webSocket: WebSocket,
            t: Throwable,
            response: Response?
        ) {
            disconnect()
        }
    }

    fun connect(listener: ServerListener?) {
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(mServerUrl)
            .build()
        mWebSocket = mClient.newWebSocket(request, SocketListener())
        mListener = listener
        mMessageHandler =
            Handler(Handler.Callback { msg: Message ->
                mListener?.onNewMessage(msg.obj as String)
                true
            })
        mStatusHandler = Handler(Handler.Callback { msg: Message ->
            mListener!!.onStatusChange(msg.obj as ConnectionStatus)
            true
        })
    }

    fun disconnect() {
        mWebSocket?.cancel()
        mListener = null
        mMessageHandler?.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
        mStatusHandler?.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
    }

    fun sendMessage(message: String?) {
        mWebSocket!!.send(message!!)
    }

    
}
```

View (Fragment/Activity)

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class RoomFragment : Fragment(), ServerConnection.ServerListener {
    
    @Inject lateinit var socketConnection: ServerConnection

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate your `AppModule.kt` class with `@InstallIn(SinggltonComponent::class)`.

To know more about the hilt component, check this detail, [here](https://dagger.dev/hilt/components.html).